# How to train dropout probabilities with TensorFlow Keras API?

Tags: c#, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to fight overfitting in my model, which only has 1500 different inputs with about 300 columns each. Most of the columns are probably of very low relevance, so I came up with an idea of applying dropout to them in different proportions.

What I am looking for is to keep the average dropout probability fixed (e.g. 0.9), but have the fitting procedure redistribute the probabilities between different columns.

Right now I am using a simple sequential model like this:

```
var model = new Sequential(new Layer[] {
    new Dropout(rate: 0.9),
    new Dense(units: 4, activation: tf.nn.leaky_relu_fn),
    new Dense(units: 4, activation: tf.nn.leaky_relu_fn),
    new Dense(units: 4, activation: tf.nn.leaky_relu_fn),
    new Dense(units: 1, activation: tf.nn.leaky_relu_fn),
});

model.compile(
  optimizer: new AdamOptimizer(),
  loss: tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_logarithmic_error_fn);

model.evaluate(trainInputs, trainOutputs);
```

What can I replace the `Dropout` layer with to achieve that? I realize that would probably require using functional API instead of `Sequential`.

Comment: Dropout doesn't work that way, at least how you describe it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro there are certainly variants of it, that have trainable parameters.

Comment: @LOST if there was something like dropout with "trainable" parameters , it will put the parameters that overfit the most, (think about regularization, if the regulizer constant was a parameter, during the training it will go to a value such that there is no regularization)

Comment: @LOST A small warning concerning putting dropout just after the input, it's in general a bad idea, except in some special cases (when your input is word embeddings for example). Basically you have several options , you can regularize your network by putting dropout (not just after the input layer) and a L2 or L1 regularization. You may also want to reduce the size of your network by removing some feature that you are sure are useless (feature selection).

Comment: @LOST L1 Regularization will help to do feature selection, I suggest to you to have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184019/when-will-l1-regularization-work-better-than-l2-and-vice-versa

Comment: @LOST Yes, I know that, but you didn't mention any, are you talking about Concrete Dropout? Please be specific.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I did describe the exact way I want dropout to work.

Comment: The simplest way to solve overfitting in DNN is just to add more parameters to the model. Number of parameters >> number of training samples will do the job. I didn’t see too much effect from dropout when you have a small capacity  network like yours. From my experience, normal noise with (mean=0, stddev=hyper-param) applied to weights during gradient updates is the best solution for small models. Second best is Langevin noise. I would also try injection of noise to inputs.

Comment: What you are describing is not Dropout, the drop masks are independent of the samples. There is no guarantee that what you want to do will work.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, I am not looking for it to work as in improve the model (though it'd be great if it would), I am looking to understand what do I need to do in Keras to run that particular experiment.

Comment: @LOST First you need to have the theoretical grounding for this to work, you seem to have an idea to modify Dropout, but then how do you want to distribute the probabilities along columns? in a way that contributes to learn feature relevance? You need to answer all of that before you can think of an implementation.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro the idea is simple: assuming no overfitting, randomly dropping some irrelevant features from the model with higher probability will increase prediction error more, than dropping relevant features.

Technically, you could just bump keep_prob of each feature, that was not dropped by 1/train_error, then just normalize them back, so that avg drop probability is equal to desired one. I am assuming one could use gradients instead of 1/traini_error too.

As for relevance, assuming no overfitting, the model would prefer irrelevant features to be dropped more often, than relevant.